# log4j2,yml - ThreadContext value is empty

Tags: log4j2

I am using spring-boot-starter-log4j2:2.1.2.RELEASE with log4j2.yml file.
on my application code,

```
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(LoggingAspect.class);
...
ThreadContext.put("hostname", InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName());
...
logger.error("message");
```

and log4j2.yml file,

```
Appenders:
  RollingRandomAccessFile:
   - name: Alerts
     filename: ...
     filePattern: ...
     PatternLayout:
      Pattern: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %X{hostname}:%m%n"
```

on log file, hostname is missing while timestamp and message is showing as expected.
I've tried ${ctx:hostname}, $${ctx:hostname} but so far nothing is working for me.

Please, guide me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

%X{hostname} would only work if you added a hostname value to the ThreadContext. But you don’t need to do that. Log4J automatically populates a hostname variable for you. So just specify ${hostName} in your pattern.

Comment: I've changed to "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p ${hostname}:%m%n" but still not showing.it's showing "2021-04-01 11:45:54 ERROR ${hostname}: messages... it's not taking it.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the answer for anyone else who finds this.